# AngularJS: How to include an HTML page into a dialog?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to change dynamically the content of a dialog. I have several pages in HTML that I want to get in my dialog by changing the *url*.

```
<md-buttonng-click="showDialog($event,'myurl/page-1.html')">Show dialog-1</md-button>
<md-buttonng-click="showDialog($event,'myurl/page-2.html')">Show dialog-2</md-button>
<md-buttonng-click="showDialog($event,'myurl/page-3.html')">Show dialog-3</md-button>
```

so I tried to do as below:

**JavaScript/AngularJS**:

```
(function () {
    angular.module('myApp', ['ngMaterial']).controller('AppCtrl', AppCtrl);
    function AppCtrl($mdDialog, $scope) {
         $scope.data = {url: 'Hello World'}; // "myurl/page.html" <--- I want to add external page here
         $scope.hideDialog = $mdDialog.hide;
         $scope.showDialog = showDialog;

         function showDialog(evt) {
              $scope.data.dialogOpen = true;
              $mdDialog.show({
                   targetEvent: evt,
                   scope: $scope.$new(),
                   template:
                   '<md-dialog>' +
                   '<md-toolbar>' + 
                   '  <div class="md-toolbar-tools"><h2>Mango (Fruit)</h2></div>' + 
                   '</md-toolbar>' + 
                   '  <md-content>{{data.url}}</md-content>' +
                   '  <div class="md-actions">' +
                   '    <md-button ng-click="data.dialogOpen=false;hideDialog()">' +
                   '      Close' +
                   '    </md-button>' +
                   '  </div>' +
                   '</md-dialog>'
              });
         }
    }
}());
```

[<kbd>Plunker</kbd>](http://plnkr.co/edit/AEyUdWxdVETEJaZK1LSv?p=preview)

I tried to add the path of my page in `$scope.data`, but I know that this will never work. 
So, is there a way to add path to external content to an AngularJS dialog?

Comment: That is not the angular way. Why not including HTML in your page and dynamically hide/show it? Speaking of `ng-if` directive

Comment: why don't you give us some plunker?

Comment: @smnbbrv http://plnkr.co/edit/AEyUdWxdVETEJaZK1LSv?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

You could use ng-Route or ui router for this:

```
App.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider

        // route for the home page
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl : 'pages/home.html',
            controller  : 'mainController'
        })

        // route for the about page
        .when('/about', {
            templateUrl : 'pages/about.html',
            controller  : 'aboutController'
        })

        // route for the contact page
        .when('/contact', {
            templateUrl : 'pages/contact.html',
            controller  : 'contactController'
        });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use an external file for the content of your dialog you should use `templateUrl` when showing the dialog instead of `template`. You can see more options to setup your dialog here: https://material.angularjs.org/0.9.6/#/api/material.components.dialog/service/$mdDialog

I forked your plunkr and made the changes to it to load the dialog content from external files. Take a look at this working example:

http://plnkr.co/edit/WHQko1l4p7xHQx0dz5wh?p=preview